# WooCommerce issue: REST API request returns "rest_disabled" code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

With WooCommerce, I request all of the api and it return:

```json
{
    "code": "rest_disabled",
    "message": "The service is currently disabled.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

how to fix this

I follow the doc and try to use postman to request `/wp-json/wc/v3` ,but it still can't work.

Answer (score 1):

Enable REST API in WooCommerce:

1. Log in to your WordPress admin dashboard.
2. Go to WooCommerce > Settings.
3. Click on the "Advanced" tab.
4. Check the box that says "Enable REST API." Save your changes.

Comment: i can't find "Enable REST API." ,but i found a checkbox says "Enable the legacy REST API",is this one?

Comment: Yes you have to enable the Enable the legacy REST API.